# Android firebase no data query

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im using the Android SDK for firebase database.

In the database I have a structure where I keep the messages ordered by user, that way if I need their messages I just query by user.

```
myDatabase -> messages -> JonDoe
                            -> "You forgot your mail"
                            -> "Buy groceries"
                       -> JaneDoe
                            -> "Dog's birthday!"
```

The problem is if the user doesnt exist the listener keeps waiting forever, and I want to show "You have no messages" in that case. (For example, if I query the user "CharlesDoe" in the example above)

Is there a way to check if a reference exists before/after/during a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on

```
DatabaseReference root =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference user = 
root.child("myDatabase").child("messages").child("CharlesDoe");
user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        // run some code
    }else{
    Toast.makeText(this,"no messages",Toast.Length_LONG).show();

    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
```

Comment: Excelent, worked like a charm!, I was using the "onChildEventListener" and with that listener this answer won't work, made a few changes and everything's fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DatabaseReference root =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference user = root.child("myDatabase").child("messages");
user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.child("CharlesDoe").exists()) {
            // run some code
        }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"no messages",Toast.Length_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Here it will query on node `messages` and then it will check if the child exists and do the required.